# How to give concatenate function results to a class in python 2.7

Tags: python, function, class

So this is a quick code for Rock Scissors Paper I 've made. It works fine and it is written pretty simply in relevance to other codes I have seen (i think), however I have a problem with the score keeping. Algorithmically speaking I need to save the score in a class, outside the loop Play - Results - Score of last game - Rematch, and to do that I have to connect somehow the Score of last game with the Score class so that it concatenates each game.

My code is bellow:

```
import random


def main():
    pick_list = ["Rock","Paper","Scissors"]
    player_pick = str(raw_input("Rock, Scissors, Paper! Make your Pick! "))
    pc_pick = random.choice(pick_list)
    if player_pick not in pick_list:
        print "Oops, looks like you didn't pick correctly. Try again!"
        main()
    else:    
        print "Your pick was " + player_pick
        print "My pick was " + pc_pick
    results(pc_pick,player_pick)
    table_score(results,pc_pick,player_pick)
    Score(pc_pick, player_pick)
    rematch()


def results(pc_pick,player_pick):
    if pc_pick == player_pick:
        print "It's a tie!"
    elif pc_pick == "Rock" and player_pick == "Paper":
        print "You win!"
        return "Victory"
    elif pc_pick == "Rock" and player_pick == "Scissors":
        print "Sorry, I win"
        return "Loss"
    elif pc_pick == "Scissors" and player_pick == "Rock":
        print "You win!"
        return "Victory"
    elif pc_pick == "Scissors" and player_pick == "Paper":
        print "Sorry, I win"
        return "Loss"
    elif pc_pick == "Paper" and player_pick == "Scissors":
        print "You win!"
        return "Victory"
    elif pc_pick == "Paper" and player_pick == "Rock":
        print "Sorry, I win"
        return "Loss"


def rematch():
    challenge = str(raw_input('Wanna go again? [Y/n]'))
    positive_answers =['Y','y', 'yes','Yes']
    negative_answers = ['N','n','No','no']
    if challenge in positive_answers:
        main()
    elif challenge in negative_answers:
        print "Goodbye!"
        raw_input("Press any key to exit")
    else:
        print "Sorry I didn't get that, try again"
        rematch()    


def table_score(results, pc_pick, player_pick):
    pc_score = 0
    player_score = 0
    if results(pc_pick, player_pick) == "Victory":
        player_score += 1
    elif results(pc_pick,player_pick) == "Loss":
        pc_score += 1
    else:
        player_score += 0
        pc_score += 0
    print "Player:" + str(player_score)
    print "Pc:" + str(pc_score)


class Score():
    pass

main()
```

The thing is that because of my rematch function, I need to keep "saving" the score somewhere outside the loop. I know it's a stupid thing but I just got stuck. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so far I 've managed to solve the problem with this code:

```
import random


def main():
    pick_list = ["Rock","Paper","Scissors"]
    player_pick = str(raw_input("Rock, Scissors, Paper! Make your Pick! "))
    pc_pick = random.choice(pick_list)
    if player_pick not in pick_list:
        print "Oops, looks like you didn't pick correctly. Try again!"
        main()
    else:    
        print "Your pick was " + player_pick
        print "My pick was " + pc_pick
    results(pc_pick,player_pick)
    table_score(results,pc_pick,player_pick)
    print "The score so far is... You: ",Score.player_score ,"Me", Score.pc_score
    rematch()


def results(pc_pick,player_pick):
    if pc_pick == player_pick:
        print "It's a tie!"
    elif pc_pick == "Rock" and player_pick == "Paper":
        print "You win!"
        return "Victory"
    elif pc_pick == "Rock" and player_pick == "Scissors":
        print "Sorry, I win"
        return "Loss"
    elif pc_pick == "Scissors" and player_pick == "Rock":
        print "You win!"
        return "Victory"
    elif pc_pick == "Scissors" and player_pick == "Paper":
        print "Sorry, I win"
        return "Loss"
    elif pc_pick == "Paper" and player_pick == "Scissors":
        print "You win!"
        return "Victory"
    elif pc_pick == "Paper" and player_pick == "Rock":
        print "Sorry, I win"
        return "Loss"


def rematch():
    challenge = str(raw_input('Wanna go again? [Y/n]'))
    positive_answers =['Y','y', 'yes','Yes']
    negative_answers = ['N','n','No','no']
    if challenge in positive_answers:
        main()
    elif challenge in negative_answers:
        print "Goodbye!"
        raw_input("Press any key to exit")
    else:
        print "Sorry I didn't get that, try again"
        rematch()    


def table_score(results, pc_pick, player_pick):
    pc_score = 0
    player_score = 0
    if results(pc_pick, player_pick) == "Victory":
        Score.player_score += 1
    elif results(pc_pick,player_pick) == "Loss":
        Score.pc_score += 1
    else:
        Score.player_score += 0
        Score.pc_score += 0
    print "Player:" + str(player_score)
    print "Pc:" + str(pc_score)


class Score:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pc_score = 0
        self.player_score = 0
Score = Score()

main()
```

The only problem I have is that the output gives me 3 times the "It's a tie" output (if it is a tie) and twice the  "I win" "You win" outputs... I cannot figure out why yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
class Score(object):
    pc_score = 0
    player_score = 0

    def update_score(self, pc_score, player_score):
        self.pc_score += pc_score
        self.player_score += player_score
```

Comment: Yes, I know that, but the problem is a bit more complicated. Where and how am I going to call this class? Cause in the main function I got the rematch function which will run from scratch the game. So how am I going to connect the main function's score with this class, is what I really wonder. Thank you for your reply though